# Sum the width of all images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the sum of all image widths.

I tried to get the values in an array so that I could calculate the sum of them but still not working, but it should be something really simple indeed, all I want is the sum of the image width values.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let images = document.querySelectorAll('#draggable img');
    let widths = [];
    images.forEach(each => {
        each.addEventListener("load", () => {
            widths.push(each.width)
        });
    });
    console.log(widths); // this is logging the array!
    const total = widths.reduce(function(a, b){ return a + b; }); 
    console.log("total is : " + total ); // this is crashing!
}
```

Comment: Try to pass an `initial value` to your reduce function as second param although it is optional
 `const total = widths.reduce(function(a, b){ return a + b; }, 0);`

Comment: It worked fine for me (running the `push` synchronously instead of in the load listener since I wasn't actually loading the images.) If you're successfully logging the values outside of the listener, your use of `reduce` seems sound. If the problem is something weird with your browser, maybe you could replace the `reduce` with something older like `let total = 0; for(let width of widths){ total += width}`  or use Morlo's suggestion. I guess you could throw in a `parseInt` for good measure, too...

Comment: Morlo's solution resolves the issue without load event listener and adding a time out loop instead, visible here: https://codepen.io/alexlais/pen/QWLEqMv BUT the only downside with this is that if the images loaded faster - and as much as we can optionally change the time out for shorter - we are working under a predetermined timeout and I feel it would be better to work with the "real" timeout available by the load event listener. If we could use the event listener to resolve this issue I think it would be better. WITHOUT TIME OUT not working: https://codepen.io/alexlais/pen/zYOBoRm

Comment: @cat  can you try that in the codepen?

Answer (score 1):

Your `widths Array` might be empty (your are populating it with a load event) and your are calling reduce on it without initialValue.
This will cause an error, [see Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) ,

You could just do this:

```
widths.reduce((acc, width) => (acc + width), 0);
```

**Update 1, Base on your Codepen and your comments.**. The load event listener is not really neaded. There is a compatibily issue with IE < 9, which support `attachEvent` not `addEventListener`. I will suggest to use a timer with a recursive function.

```
sumWidths = () => {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('#draggable img');
  let sum = 0;

  images.forEach(({ width }) => {
    if(!width){ // not width or width 0 means the image has not been fully loaded.
      setTimeout(this.sumWidths, 500) // delay half second to allow image to load and try again;
      return;
    } else {
      sum = sum + width;
    }
  });

  // This function can be created on parent component
  // or use state management library or what ever befit your needs.
  saveImageWidths(sum); // Create this function

  // Or save `sum` to the state of this component!!!!
  this.setState(state => ({ ...state, widthsSum: sum }));
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.sumWidths();
}
```

**Update 2. Using load event listeer**
Take a loot at your forked working [codepen here](https://codepen.io/babyboy/pen/vYBKezO?editors=1111)

```
function totalImagesWidth() {
  let reportWidth = 0;
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('#imagesContainer img');
  let imagesWidth = [];
  images.forEach(each => {
    each.addEventListener("load", () => {
      imagesWidth.push(each.width);

      if (imagesWidth.length === images.length) {
        reportWidth = (imagesWidth.reduce((a, b) => { return a + b; }, 0));
        showResult(reportWidth);
      }
    });
  });

  function showResult(reportWidth){
    const results = document.createElement("p");
    results.innerHTML = `
      Images: ${images} <br />
      Total images: ${images.length} <br />
      <code>imagesWidth</code> length: ${imagesWidth.length} <br />
      Images widths: ${imagesWidth.toString()} <br />
      <b>SUM: ${reportWidth}</b>`;
    document.body.appendChild(results);
    console.log(imagesWidth);
  }
}

totalImagesWidth()
```

Comment: I took `console.log(widths); // this is logging the array!` to mean the width values were available in the array.

Comment: The load event is necessary because the tag being queried does not mean the image itself is loaded. In which case the width is unknown.

Comment: This is crashing TypeError: images.reduce is not a function
Carousel.componentDidMount
src/components/carousel/index.jsx:32
  29 | componentDidMount() {
  30 | 
  31 |   const images = document.querySelectorAll('#draggable img') || [];
> 32 |   const total = images.reduce((acc, image) => {
     | ^  33 |     if(image.width){
  34 |       acc = acc + image.width;
  35 |     }

Comment: @Mig, you are very right. I have edited  my answer.

Comment: I dont know why I can't get this to work, I created a codepen for you to see, you can fork it and make changes https://codepen.io/alexlais/pen/zYOBoRm it is working a bit different there, not getting the same behavior, not getting the items added to the array at all. Long story short all I want is to calculate the full width of all images combined, can you put a solution functioning in the codepen please?

Comment: @Alex, you can sum the widths in your `forEach`  and save the result in your parent component; I edited the answer to match your need.

Comment: YAY THAT WORKED! I created a short plain javscript example of this and finally it is adding up all the widths of the images. if you change the width of images on the CSS it updates correctly, check it out! https://codepen.io/alexlais/pen/QWLEqMv

Comment: @Alex do upvote or maked this solution as aswer if it has helped you.

Comment: I just wish we could do this using the load event listener instead of adding a time out, and I am even logging the array with the widths here so I don't understand why the load event listener model cant work: https://codepen.io/alexlais/full/zYOBoRm if you open the browser console you will see the array there with the widths. The code window is here:  https://codepen.io/alexlais/pen/zYOBoRm

Comment: @Alex, forked an fixed your codepend to work with event listener. I updated my answer as well. https://codepen.io/babyboy/pen/vYBKezO?editors=1111

Comment: Not sure what is the issue now but when I open your solution 2 in full view and refresh it crashes: https://codepen.io/babyboy/full/vYBKezO refresh to crash

Comment: perhaps the load event listener for images should indeed be avoided, perhaps thats the lesson we learned with this exercise?  :)

Comment: Perhaps all good, its just a codepen bug I am thinking now. I will try this in the real app Monday and will see how it goes thank you soooooooo much!

Answer (score 0):

When your reduce happens, you cannot be sure the images are loaded because  the event is asynchronous from your function. You need a mechanism to make sure they were all added. Like counting the number of images until the number of items in widths is the same as the number of images.

```
function whenTotalWidthReady(cb) {
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('#draggable img');
  if (images.length==0) cb(0);
  let widths = [];
  images.forEach(each => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      widths.push(img.width);
      if (widths.length==images.length) {
        cb(widths.reduce(function(a, b){ return a + b; }););
      }
    }
    img.src = each.src;
  });
}
```

I don't know if creating intermediary Image objects is mandatory, but that is the way I know works. Also I do not think there is a problem with your `reduce`. As far as I know, the initial value is optional. But you still can pass "0" as suggested.

Now the way this version works is because it is all asynchronous, you pass a call back function as an argument. And this function will be called with the total width once images are ready.

```
function componentDidMount() {
  whenTotalWidthReady(function(totalWidth) {
    console.log("The total width of images is: " + totalWidth);
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I am thinking but how can I write a setTimeout like that?

Comment: Not set timeout I was wrong. I’ve edited my answer. But the idea is the same. It needs to wait for the data to be available before reducing.

Comment: But how can I do that?

Comment: componentDidmount does not take an argument: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with react. I thought you created this one. But it’s the same thing. Just change the name of the function I gave you and then you call it from inside componentDidMount.

Comment: I’ve updated my example so that it is called inside coponentDidMount.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` like so:

```
const res = [...images].reduce((a, { width = 0 }) => a + width, 0);
```

Comment: This does not do anything and crashes, something is wrong with it.

Comment: Works perfectly when I test it @Alex - must be your code.

Comment: I created a codepen for you to see, you can fork it and make changes codepen.io/alexlais/pen/zYOBoRm can you test it there?

Comment: @JackBashford the OP's `images` is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an array, which is why he is correct that `.reduce` does not exist on his `images`.  You probably created an array directly.  The OP should use `Array.from(images)` to get `.reduce`.

Comment: Whoops - fixed @Alex, see my updated answer. Thanks dwmorrin for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#draggable img'));
```

`reduce` is not available on a DOM node collection.  Make it an Array first.

**Update:**

Using your codepen: this logs the desired answer:

```js
const images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#imagesContainer img'));
const sumOfWidths = images.reduce((a, b) => a + b.width, 0);
console.log({sumOfWidths}); // => 600
```

This assumes the images have already loaded.

Here is a solution for waiting for them to load with promises, which worked in your codepen: (this is not meant to be a *good* example of using promises - just a simplistic example... consider adding reject handlers for instance)

```js
function totalImagesWidth() {
  const images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#imagesContainer img'));
  const loadHandler = img => new Promise(resolve => {
    img.addEventListener("load", () => resolve({}));
  });
  Promise.all(images.map(loadHandler)).then(results);
  function results() {
    const sumOfWidths = images.reduce((a, b) => a + b.width, 0);
    const results = document.createElement("p");
    results.innerHTML = `
      Images: ${images} <br />
      Total images: ${images.length} <br />
      <b>SUM: ${sumOfWidths}</b>`;
    document.body.appendChild(results);
    console.log(sumOfWidths);
  }
}
totalImagesWidth()
```

Comment: We are trying to run reduce on a created variable, not the dom node itself, check my updated codepen https://codepen.io/alexlais/pen/zYOBoRm?editors=0110 if you console log here https://codepen.io/alexlais/full/zYOBoRm you can see the array with the 3 widths but I cant seem able to use that to calculate the total width. You can fork the codepen and make changes.

Comment: @Alex - what doesn't work in your codepen is that your code races through the `results.innerHTML` part long before your callbacks have had a chance to set the value of `reportWidth`.  When `reportWidth` is set, _that's_ when you need to do the `results.innerHTML`, i.e. call that as a function when `reportWidth` is finally ready or mess around with Promises as I added to my answer.

Comment: Oh ok gotcha thank you very much your answer working here now as you presented https://codepen.io/alexlais/pen/wvwWPar thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the value of a variable that is supposed to be updated in the future. How about letting it be updated for an expected number of times (which is the total number of images) and then when it has, find the total.

I didn't run my code but am looking at something like

```
constructor() {
    this.widths = [];
}

componentDidMount() {
    let images = document.querySelectorAll('#draggable img');

    images.forEach(each => {
        each.addEventListener('load', () => {
            widths.push(each.width);

            if (widths.length === images.length) {
                this.reportWidth(widths.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0));
            }
        });
    });
}

reportWidth (width) {
    console.log(`Width is finally found to be ${width}`);
}
```

Comment: So I tried it as a variable but still not getting updated. Can you check my updated codepen https://codepen.io/alexlais/pen/zYOBoRm?editors=0110 Amazingly, if you console log here: https://codepen.io/alexlais/full/zYOBoRm you can see the array with the 3 widths right there but I cant seem able to use that to calculate the total width. You can fork the codepen and make changes.

Comment: Thanks men your idea to count the loops is what made it work after all, nice job it is working here https://codepen.io/alexlais/pen/YzKWYpa?editors=0010 I will use this one for the project, this is for the carousel behavior to slide an image carousel only for the total width of the images, thanks a bunch you made it happen!

Comment: Cool! Do remember to upvote and mark it as the selected answer.